# How do I set a lua.dll so lua.exe won't ask for it in every directory?

Tags: c++, c, windows, lua

Every time I enter `lua my_script.lua` in command line, it prompts me for lua53.dll on the same folder. How do I set a path so I won't need to have a copy of the lua library in every folder that I want to run a .lua file? I wonder if it is made via parameters or if I should build my own .exe from the .c files using environment variables, but I don't really know.

I've downloaded the binaries from http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net (v5.3.2 - may 19th) and have put lua.exe inside C:/Windows/System32.

Comment: `lua53.dll` is part of _lua_, or is your custom `.dll` (needed by `my_script.lua`)? If it's the former, did you try copying it next to `lua.exe`?

Comment: Moving `lua.exe` to `C:/Windows/System32` was the wrong thing to do. If you wanted lua available from the command prompt you should have added the lua path to your `%PATH%` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the directory from which the application is loaded is the first location being checked for the DLL file. If you put the DLL next to the location of `lua.exe` it came with, the DLL should be found and loaded by the system.

It may be better to not put application files into your system folders. Just create a separate folder and put your Lua files (.exe and .dll) there. You can then add that folder to PATH environment variable, so that it can be found when you run it as `lua`.